# Flutter integration_test - add --flavor argument in VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test

I have a suite of integration tests for a Flutter app.  I would like to run them using the VS Code Testing tab, so that I can easily see info about what tests passed/failed, etc.

[image: VS Code Testing View]

This worked fine before we implemented [flavors](https://medium.com/@devrient.jonas/flutter-profiles-in-vscode-product-flavors-c95231818005).  Now that flavors are defined in launch.json, running the tests require a --flavor argument, but I can't seem to set that in the UI.

If I try to run them on iOS using the Testing tab in VS Code, I get this error:

`The Xcode project defines schemes: dev, prod, qa Exception: You must specify a --flavor option to select one of the available schemes.`

I can run `flutter test integration_test --flavor dev`, but the terminal fills up with logs and it's harder to find out which tests failed and why.

Comment: What version of Flutter do you use? There was an issue with flavors but that has actually been fixed some time ago.

Comment: @RobDil I'm currently using Flutter version 3.7.6 and am still experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just struggled with it too. You need to add this in your launch.json:

```
{
        "name": "integration test",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        // Define your flavor (here: foo) that you use in tests
        "toolArgs": [
            "--flavor",
            "foo",
        ],
        // This is important: set it only for integration_test
        "templateFor": "integration_test",
    },
```

Thats it! Now you can run them on VSCode too.